# Understanding 「あいつの事だ、陸でも見えりゃ自力で下りるだろう」

Tags: manga

I need help understanding the panel below from One Piece chapter 8. Zoro was trying to rescue Luffy who got trapped in a bird's mouth. He met Buggy's pirates along the way.

[image]

Specifically on this part

> とにかくまっすぐ漕げ
>
> あいつの事だ
>
> 陸でも見えりゃ自力で下りるだろう

What does 「あいつの事だ」 mean here? How does it connect with the rest of the sentence?

Who is the subject for 「自力で下りる」?  Buggy's pirates, right?

Comment: Note, this is 見えりゃ＝見えれば, not 見えりや.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can roughly translated to *If he can see land, he'll get off the bird by himself, because that's what he's like.*

"～の事だからな" is a word that describes a particular person(in this case, Luffy), indicating that he/she has some habitual or character trait. It's used when the speaker's subjective judgment is expressed on the basis of that person's characteristics.

As you can probably tell from the explanation so far, "自力で下りるだろう" refers to Luffy. It means that he will get off the bird by himself.

I wonder if Luffy can do that though, I only vaguely remember One Piece, but I'm pretty sure he couldn't swim, right?